# Add band to Image in Earth Engine App

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to add a new band to an image in Earth Engine APP but it doesn't appear to be working. I can get it to work for an image collection but not a single image.

Here is my code:

```
var test = ee.Image.expression(('VV')/('VH')).rename('test');

ee.initialize();
image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20170415T062305_20170415T062330_016151_01AAE9_5D0F');

var combined = image.addBands(test);

var visParams = {"opacity":1,"bands":["VV"],"min":-30,"max":10,"gamma":1};

var eeMapConfig = combined.getMap(visParams);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine, per https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#stack-exchange.

Comment: For migration see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work